# Control to drag and drop buttons in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I just want to know which in which control (wrapPanel, listView etc..) its possible to make items draggable? When I say items i mean buttons - want to have x buttons in control and change theirs positions, so if Ill drag button 1 and drop in index 10 i want rest of buttons to change their positions (from 2 to 10, id/position -1). 
If that possible in both cotnrols, in which one is easier?

Answer (score 1):

This article has a dragging canvas example.[Dragging Elements in a Canvas](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15354/Dragging-Elements-in-a-Canvas)

For the positions you can save the positions of each element in a property and then when you drop an element you get his position, calculate its boundaries. You would then loop through all the elements and modify their position depending on what you need

Comment: Hmm, i tried to do it with buttons. But after added that 3 methods nothing really happened:

Comment: void bnt_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Button l = (Button)sender;
            if (l != null)
            {
                DragDrop.DoDragDrop(l, l.Content, DragDropEffects.Copy);
            }
        }

Comment: private void listBox1_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            ListBox lb = sender as ListBox;
            if (lb != null)
            {
                lb.Items.Add(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text));
            }
        }

Comment: private void listBox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
            {
                e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
            }
        }

Comment: why use the button. You can just create the elements you want to drag and make them look like buttons if you want

Comment: I need click event for that element. Actually it should work like list of categories - for example 2 buttons (categories) Fruits, Vegetables - after click Fruits show another wrapPanel/listBox with Apple, Bananas etc. But there will be a lot of categories so I want to move them ( to have most popular on begining and less on the end)

Comment: Also i'v changed buttons to labels, check "AllowDrop" property in ListView and still doesnt work

Comment: You can add a click event on any element by using `item.Click += new EventHandler(ClickMeEvent);` and then you define `void ClickMeEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //Do whatever you want
}`

Comment: Ok, but question is why drag and drop with labels on listbox doesnt work?